# what is common practice of saving function definitions in asp.net-mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've a question, not about code, but about a good practice. 
in my asp.net mvc app i need to write function which calculates longest increasing subsequence, so where should i save this function? 
my opinion is to create different file in my project create class and add this function there.

Comment: You should research design patterns. SOLID principles etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by thinking about your project in terms of layers:

- You have a presentation layer or the UI, consisting of the views and controllers that decide how actions are executed and how.
- You have a data access layer, in charge of communicating with your database.
- You have a business logic layer, where your business rules and domain models are defined.

> In my asp.net mvc app i need to write function which calculates longest increasing subsequence, so where should i save this function?

You can answer this by determining which layer should be in charge of executing this logic. Does this belong to the presentation layer? Certainly not, as the UI does not care how you calculate the subsequence. So this function should not be placed in the controllers.

My suggestion is then to create a service that will be in charge of executing this calculation. Something like:

```
public class CalculationsService : ICalculationService
{
    public int[] GetLongestIncreasingSubsequence(int [] seq)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a silly request, but maybe add the code for the interface, assuming that ICalculationService is going to have the GetLongestIncreasingSubsequence on it.